# как составить sql запрос для нахождения максимального значения у каждого уникального идентификатора?

Tags: sql

Как получить максимальную зарплату salary для кажджого department_id из таблицы employees.

```
select unique department_id, salary
from employee 
where salary=
(select max(salary) from employees)
```

как сделать, чтобы последняя строка выводила максимальное значение для каждого уникального идентификатора, а не 1 максимальное значение? 
Либо как разбить таблицу на подтаблицы,сгруппированные по id отдела?
[image: db schema]

Comment: `select department_id, max(salary) ....  group by department_id`

Comment: @teran, пожалуйста, напишите это в ответ)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб какой смысл плодить десятки ответов на базовые знания sql. надо закрыть с дублем подходящим.

Comment: @teran, если есть на что закрыть дублем - давайте закроем) если нет - то можно и в ответ написать. То что вопрос по базовым вещам - не делает его плохим. Такие вопросы также нужны и важны)